# I need to automatically hide rows containing dates that are not the first of the month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11O3eWzuvwO4qeXbciVoibhR2ZRwIIEXqizOqcs8rqoI/edit?usp=sharing

this is what i've got so far but its missing some months and not hiding the 30 & 31 days of the month.

,,,,

,,,,

```
function hideDates()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getSheetByName("UI Data");
    var v = s.getRange("C:C").getValues();
    for (var i = s.getLastRow(); i > 2; i--) 
    {
        var t = v[i - 0];
        if (t != "") 
        {
            var u = new Date(t);
            var dateToday = 1;
            var  testDate = u.getDate();
            if (t >"")
            if (dateToday != testDate)
            {
                s.hideRows(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I  think this is because of different timezone between spreadsheet and script, you've to make sure timezone between both should be same, if format of your date is same as in spreadsheet you can use `substring` method to just get date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Spreadsheet, it seems that the value of column "C" is like `01/02/2022 00:00:00`. If this format is constant, as a simple method, how about retrieving the values as the string value? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function hideDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("UI Data");
  var v = s.getRange("C:C").getDisplayValues();
  v.forEach(([c], i) => {
    if (Number(c.split("/")[0]) != 1) {
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this modification, the value like `01/02/2022 00:00:00` is retrieved as the string value, and `01` is retrieved as the number, and then, `hideRows` is run by comparing it with `1`.

#### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)